# FusedLocationClient vs LocationManager in Initial Location

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location, android-fusedlocation

Deciding between `LocationManager` or `FusedLocationClient` in Android is pretty easy, just go for FusedLocationClient, since it will save power and it is recommended as a best practice.

However, I'm in a situation where I have to fetch the "initial location" of the device, or simply the current/last known location. The thing that FusedLocationClient might consider as null in 3 different scenarios. ([see here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#last-known)).

And that won't change until the actual location of the device changes, when requesting location updates of course. ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html))

In LocationManager provided by android framework, you can easily get the last known location by simply calling `mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` but to use it for listening to updates costs a lot of power.

What is the best solution here? Is it reasonable to combine both? If yes, how to use LocationManager only to get the current location and then disable it to save power?

Comment: I combined both of them. I used getLastKnownLocation as a first step, but observed location updates with FusedLocation API

Comment: It is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36975498#comment125 Did you find a workaround for that?

Comment: @Tiago I checked first the FusedLocation, if it is null, I use the old LocationManager to get current location and then compare it with all available providers to get the best location among them all

Answer (score 4):

You can go through [this document](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html):

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(60000) ;     // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
          .setFastestInterval(10000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
if(mFusedLocationClient == null) {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext);
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);
    }
 private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        if(location != null) {...you can get updated location
}}
//REMOVE LOCATION UPDATES
mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I know I can request location updates, but they wont be delivered until the device's location actually changes. Meanwhile if the location never changed, you will "sometimes" get null when trying to getting the last locaiton

Comment: Ok..I understood. If you disable location service then you will getting null location because it clear cache. For that reason, you have to create a new client and request location updates yourself. please refer **last point** again in [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and after getting location you can remove it.

Comment: It will keep returning null, the location wont be updated until the location is changed and the listener is called

Comment: No location will be updated after request of location update by another applications like google map or another

Comment: **getLastKnownLocation** is based on stored location in device by another applications which are requesting for location updates. so both LocationManager and FusedLocationAPI give you last known location which stored in device by another applications otherwise location will be null